# Getting php crawler to skip specific urls

Tags: php, laravel, web-crawler, sitemap

I have this GenerateSitemap.php file where I can configure the crawler, but I don't understand how I should make the crawler skip some specific URLs for example (https://example.com/noindex-url). I have read this but I can't get my head around it. https://github.com/spatie/laravel-sitemap

```
namespace Example\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Spatie\Sitemap\SitemapGenerator;
use Spatie\Sitemap\Tags\Url;
use Spatie\Crawler\Crawler;

class GenerateSitemap extends Command
{
    /**
     * The console command name.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'sitemap:generate';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Generate the sitemap.';

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle()
    {   
        $siteURL = 'https://example.com';
        SitemapGenerator::create($siteURL)
            ->configureCrawler(function (Crawler $crawler) {
                $crawler->ignoreRobots();
            })
            ->hasCrawled(function (Url $url) {
                if ((string)$url->path() === '/') {
                    return;
                }

                $this->output->writeln('Crawled: ' . (string)$url->path());

                return $url;
            })
            ->writeToFile(public_path('sitemap.xml'));
```

Comment: You should always use triple `=` to (strict) check against a string. What are the urls you don't want to include?

Comment: For example (https://example.com/noindex-url)

Comment: `if ((string)$url->path() === 'example.com/noindex-url') { ... }` does not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ((string)$url->path() === '/noindex-url') {
    return;
}
```

This did it!

So this is what it looks like now:

```
namespace Example\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Spatie\Sitemap\SitemapGenerator;
use Spatie\Sitemap\Tags\Url;
use Spatie\Crawler\Crawler;

class GenerateSitemap extends Command
{
    /**
     * The console command name.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'sitemap:generate';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Generate the sitemap.';

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle()
    {   
        $siteURL = 'https://example.com';
        SitemapGenerator::create($siteURL)
            ->configureCrawler(function (Crawler $crawler) {
                $crawler->ignoreRobots();
            })
            ->hasCrawled(function (Url $url) {
                if ((string)$url->path() === '/') {
                    return;
                }

                if ((string)$url->path() === '/noindex-url') {
                    return;
                }
                $this->output->writeln('Crawled: ' . (string)$url->path());

                return $url;
            })
            ->writeToFile(public_path('sitemap.xml'));
```